# What is the Maximum Size Limit supported by the Profile Editor Picture?

Tags: my-site, my-profile, limitations

When I edit my user profile on a My Site with default settings, I received an error for a picture that is too large.

The message says "Choose a smaller file to upload."

I've received this message for a picture with file size 5MBs or larger, but not one that is around 1MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~4.7MB is the limit (5000000 bytes).

Comment: Sounds like it could be right. Do you have a reference?

Comment: public ProfileImagePicker()
        {
          this.m_strErrorMsg = string.Empty;
          this.m_profileType = ProfileType.User;
          this.m_nMaxBytes = 0x4c4b40;
          this.m_nTextboxSize = 30;
        }


In Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ProfileImagePicker.

Answer (score 0):

The user profile images are stored on the My Site host site collection in a Picture Library called "User Photos".
Since the images are stored as files in a library, the default limit of 50 MB per file should apply there too. (You can increase the limit to 2GB per file)

Here is the Technet article with the library limits:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary

For your situation: has anybody made any customization on the "User Photos" library? Maybe somebody has added an event receiver to check the file size of the photo being uploaded?

Here is a detailed article on User Profile pictures in 2010. Maybe it can give you some info:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spsocial/archive/2011/01/07/photo-management-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: Great links and information, but I'm afraid they don't offer the correct answer. I've tried this on two seperate farms. Have you tried uploading a 5MB image? I think you may find you receive the same error message.